# Get elements in list by condition against other list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two lists of the same object, and they are of different sizes.

I wan't all in objects List1 where tmDate does not exist in List2.

```
public class MyObj
{
    public MyObj(DateTime tmDate)
    {
        this.tmDate = tmDate;
    }
    public DateTime tmDate { get; set; }
}

var List1 = new List<MyObj>();
        var List2 = new List<MyObj>();

        List1.Add(new MyObj(new DateTime(2015, 01, 01)));
        List1.Add(new MyObj(new DateTime(2015, 01, 02)));
        List1.Add(new MyObj(new DateTime(2015, 01, 03)));

        List2.Add(new MyObj(new DateTime(2015, 01, 01)));
        List2.Add(new MyObj(new DateTime(2015, 01, 02)));

        var notMatchingObj =
            List1.Where(
                l1 => List2.Any(l2 => l2.tmDate != l1.tmDate));
```

This code gives me wrong output..I only want MyObj with tmDate 2015-01-03 in this case

Comment: what output do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
var result = list1.Where(item=>!list2.Any(item2=>item2.tmDate==item.tmDate));
```

This `list2.Any(item2=>item2.tmDate==item.tmDate)` returns true if there is any item in the `list2` with the same date with the `item`.  Otherwise it returns false. Taking it's negation, we get that we want.

On the other hand this `List2.Any(l2 => l2.tmDate != l1.tmDate)` returns true if any item found in `List2`, whose date is not the same with the date of `l1`. This doesn't mean that an object with the same date with the `l1` doesn't exist. The above will return true if the first item you check has date different with `l1`. However an item in `List2` may exist with the same date with `l1`.

Comment: Yup... this should be the same effect as just switching `Any` to `All` in the original.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
var notMatchingObj =
                from list1 in List1
                where (!List2.Any(l2 => l2.tmDate == list1.tmDate))
                select new { list1.tmDate };
```